# Cycle detection using directed graph with Apache-AGE and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am trying to detect cycles in a graph created on postgreSQl and Apache AGE.

The schema for the graph is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE modules (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dependencies (
    module_id INTEGER REFERENCES modules(id),
    dependency_id INTEGER REFERENCES modules(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (module_id, dependency_id)
);
```

and the sample data is given by

```
-- Modules
INSERT INTO modules (name, version) VALUES
('Module A', '1.0.0'),
('Module B', '1.1.0'),
('Module C', '1.2.0'),
('Module D', '2.0.0'),
('Module E', '2.1.0');

-- Dependencies
INSERT INTO dependencies (module_id, dependency_id) VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(3, 4),
(4, 5),
(5, 1);
```

Can someone guide me what the cypher query would be to detect cycles within the graph and also the nodes involved in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try working out with "WITH RECURSIVE" statement. [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) is the official documentation of it.

Other possible way is to proceed with a custom function. [Here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/postgresql-create-function/) is how you can create a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to experiment with the following query to detect cycles per your defined schema:

```
WITH RECURSIVE detect_cycles(module_id, path, cycle) AS (
SELECT module_id, ARRAY[module_id], false
FROM dependencies
UNION
SELECT d.module_id, path || d.module_id, d.module_id = ANY(path)
FROM dependencies d, detect_cycles c
WHERE d.dependency_id = c.module_id AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT * FROM detect_cycles WHERE cycle;
```

Answer (score 0):

> what the cypher query would be to detect cycles within the graph?

I've created a graph only with the cypher syntax. The commands I used to create the graph are:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
CREATE (:Person {name: 'A'})-[:RELATED_TO]->(:Person {name: 'B'})-[:RELATED_TO]->(:Person {name: 'C'})
$$) AS (a agtype);
 a 
---
(0 rows)

SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
  MATCH (a:Person {name: 'A'}), (c:Person {name: 'C'})
  CREATE (c)-[:RELATED_TO]->(a)
$$) AS (a agtype);
 a 
---
(0 rows)
```

Then, to see if there is a cycle in the graph:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
  MATCH path=(startNode)-[*]->(startNode)
  RETURN relationships(path)
$$) AS (paths agtype);
```

So, I believe you would need to somehow execute the same process as the VLE does for your custom tables.

Therefore, as @Huzaifa mentioned, using a `RECURSIVE WITH`. Something like this would probably work:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cycle_detection(module_id, dependency_id, path) AS (
  SELECT d.module_id, d.dependency_id, ARRAY[d.module_id, d.dependency_id]
  FROM dependencies d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.module_id, d.dependency_id, path || d.dependency_id
  FROM dependencies d
  JOIN cycle_detection c ON c.dependency_id = d.module_id
  WHERE NOT d.dependency_id = ALL(path)
)
SELECT path
FROM cycle_detection
WHERE module_id = ANY(path)
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive query to detect cycles in a graph in Noe4j. However, make sure that the version of Neo4j that you're using supports recursive queries.

Heres an example of how you can use cypher queries to detect cycles in your graph:

```
MATCH (n)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(n)
RETURN n AS Node, labels(n) AS Labels
```

Comment: What does your code have to do with recursive queries?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is talking about bigger cycles than self-looping vertices, which is all your example finds...

Answer (score 0):

For the detection of cycles using directed graph, you can use the following clauses:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*]->(n)
RETURN nodes(n) AS nodes_in_cycle;
```

The `RETURN` statement will give the nodes involved in the cycle

Comment: This code just causes an error...

Comment: Is `nodes` even supported in AGE? It's not listed [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/v0.6.0/functions/list_functions.html).

Answer (score -1):

The code for that would be something like:

```
g.V().as('start').
    repeat(out().as('next').
           where('next', neq('start')).
           store('path').by(id)).
    until(out().filter('it', eq('start'))).
    select('path').unfold().dedup().groupCount().unfold().
    filter(select(values).is(gt(1))).
    select(keys).unfold().as('cycle').
    select('cycle', out().where(eq('cycle')).dedup().count().as('cycleSize')).
    filter('cycleSize', gt(1)).
    select('cycle').fold()
```