# Cycle detection recursive query not working in Apache-AGE and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, graph, apache-age

I am trying to detect cycles in a graph created on postgreSQl and Apache AGE using **WITH RECURSIVE** method. Can someone guide me why my cypher query would not be able to detect cycles? I have using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76123049/21789167). Below is my trying code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dependency_path AS (
  SELECT module_id, dependency_id, ARRAY[module_id] AS path
  FROM dependencies
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dp.module_id, d.dependency_id, path || dp.module_id
  FROM dependency_path dp, dependencies d
  WHERE dp.dependency_id = d.module_id
  AND NOT (dp.path @> ARRAY[d.dependency_id])
)
SELECT path || dependency_id AS cycle
FROM dependency_path
WHERE module_id = dependency_id
AND path @> ARRAY[dependency_id];
```

Answer (score 0):

The point in code `from` should be changed to `join`

```
FROM dependency_path dp, dependencies d
```

should be changed to

```
JOIN dependencies d ON dp.dependency_id = d.module_id
```

To ensure that the join is properly performed.
and the next line should be changed from

```
AND NOT (dp.path @> ARRAY[d.dependency_id])
```

to

```
WHERE NOT (dp.path @> ARRAY[d.dependency_id])
```

This thing will make sure the condition is applied correctly.
With these changes the recursive function to detect cycles in graph should work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect the cycle, use this code

```
MATCH path=(n)-[*]->(n)
RETURN path
```

Comment: Question is about specific code not working. Why do this instead?

Answer (score 0):

For cycles detection, this customized query will work:

```
Match (a:Person)-[:relationship]-(b:Person)
where a=b
```

This query first takes the a as some person vertex and then b as person vertex and then check whether the a and b are same and if its same then it will return the values if its same.

The above query will also return the nodes in which there is a direct edge from a node to its own.

For having a cycle that has at least two nodes, we can use the following query.

```
Match (a:Person)-[:relationship*2..]-(b:Person)
where a=b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH RECURSIVE method to detect cycles, you can modify your query to ensure that the conditions and joins are applied correctly.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dependency_path AS (
  SELECT module_id, dependency_id, ARRAY[module_id] AS path
  FROM dependencies
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dp.module_id, d.dependency_id, path || dp.module_id
  FROM dependency_path dp
  JOIN dependencies d ON dp.dependency_id = d.module_id
  WHERE NOT (dp.path @> ARRAY[d.dependency_id])
)
SELECT path || dependency_id AS cycle
FROM dependency_path
WHERE module_id = dependency_id
AND path @> ARRAY[dependency_id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code, might work for you.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dependency_path AS (
  SELECT module_id, dependency_id, ARRAY[module_id, dependency_id] AS path
  FROM dependencies
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dp.module_id, d.dependency_id, path || d.dependency_id
  FROM dependency_path dp
  JOIN dependencies d ON dp.dependency_id = d.module_id
  WHERE NOT dp.path @> ARRAY[d.dependency_id]
)
SELECT path AS cycle
FROM dependency_path
WHERE module_id = dependency_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons for the query to not be detecting graphs,

1. The table where the dependencies are defined, make sure that the relationships are defined correctly. The query will not work if there are any missing dependencies.
2. Make sure that the version of PostgreSQL you're using is the correct one and that is supports the required CTE recursive syntax.